# How to handle multiple fields with the same name in symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, duplicates

I have to submit a form (sell) with multiple fields, some of them are from an entity and the others are customed fields that i can duplicate (products) with JQuery.
the problem is that in the createAction i get just one of each duplicated field (the last one).

This is my form type :

```
  $builder
        ->add('montant')
        ->add('dateDebut', 'date', array( 'input'  => 'datetime','widget' => 'single_text'))
        ->add('dateFin', 'date', array('input'  => 'datetime', 'widget' => 'single_text'))
        ->add('statutVente', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('Oui' => 'Oui','A finaliser' => 'A finaliser', 'A encaisser' => 'A encaisser', 'Non' => 'Non'  ),'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('objet', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('Entrant' => 'Entrant','Prospection' => 'Prospection', 'Renouvellement ' => 'Renouvellement' ),'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('moyenPaiement', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('CB' => 'CB','Chèque' => 'Chèque', 'Virement ' => 'Virement', 'Espèces' => 'Espèces', 'Paypal' => 'Paypal', 'Autre' => 'Autre' ),'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('numeroCommande')
        ->add('devise', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('MAD' => 'MAD','EURO' => 'EURO', 'DOLLAR ' => 'DOLLAR' ),'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('nomFacturation')
        ->add('tva', 'choice', array('choices'  => array('OUI' => 'OUI','NON' => 'NON'),'choices_as_values' => true))
        ->add('reduction')
        ->add('adresseFacturation')
        ->add('cpFacturation')
        ->add('villeFacturation')
        ->add('raison')
        ->add('produit', 'entity', array('class' => 'VENTEBundle\\Entity\\Produit', 'mapped' => false, 'attr' => array('class'=>'add_form') ))
        ->add('compte', 'text', array('mapped'=> false))
        ->add('Sujet', null, array('mapped' => false))
        ->add('sujetappel', null, array('mapped' => false))
        ->add('Note', 'textarea', array( 'attr' => array( 'placeholder'=>""),'mapped' => false))
        ->add('remindertime', 'datetime', array('date_widget' => 'single_text','time_widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm','mapped' => false,
           'attr' => array( 'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
               'data-date-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy' )))
        ->add('dateappel', 'datetime', array('date_widget' => 'single_text','time_widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy','mapped' => false,
           'attr' => array( 'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
               'data-date-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy' )))
        ->add('quantite', 'text', array('mapped' => false)) 
        ->add('montant_total', 'text', array('mapped' => false))       
        ->add('nbr_personne', 'text', array('mapped' => false))       
        ->add('duree', 'text', array('mapped' => false))       
        ->add('description', 'textarea', array('mapped' => false));
    }
```

And this is the jquery function that duplicate the fields :

```
  $("#add_product").on('click', function(){
var i=1;
var original = document.getElementById('form_container_child');
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
clone.id = "form_container_child" + ++i;
original.parentNode.append(clone);
})
```

This is my sell entity (vente)

```
<?php

namespace VENTEBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Vente
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VENTEBundle\Entity\VenteRepository")
 */
class Vente
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="montant", type="float")
     */
    private $montant;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_debut", type="date")
     */
    private $dateDebut;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_fin", type="date")
     */
    private $dateFin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="statut_vente", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $statutVente;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="objet", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $objet;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="moyen_paiement", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $moyenPaiement;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero_commande", type="string", length=120)
     */
    private $numeroCommande;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="devise", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $devise;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_facturation", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomFacturation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tva", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $tva;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="reduction", type="float")
     */
    private $reduction;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse_facturation", type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $adresseFacturation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cpfacturation", type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $cpFacturation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ville_facturation", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $villeFacturation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Raison", inversedBy="ventes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="raison_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $raison;    

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="COMPTEBundle\Entity\Compte", inversedBy="ventes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="compte_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $compte;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Venteproduit", mappedBy="vente")
     */
    private $venteproduits;    

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ventedocument", mappedBy="vente")
     */
    private $ventedocuments;


     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="ventes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user; 

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->venteproduits = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->ventedocuments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->dateCreation = new \Datetime();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set montant
     *
     * @param float $montant
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setMontant($montant)
    {
        $this->montant = $montant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get montant
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getMontant()
    {
        return $this->montant;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateDebut
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateDebut
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setDateDebut($dateDebut)
    {
        $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateDebut
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateDebut()
    {
        return $this->dateDebut;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateFin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateFin
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setDateFin($dateFin)
    {
        $this->dateFin = $dateFin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateFin
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateFin()
    {
        return $this->dateFin;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreation
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
    {
        $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreation
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateCreation()
    {
        return $this->dateCreation;
    }

    /**
     * Set statutVente
     *
     * @param string $statutVente
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setStatutVente($statutVente)
    {
        $this->statutVente = $statutVente;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get statutVente
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStatutVente()
    {
        return $this->statutVente;
    }

    /**
     * Set objet
     *
     * @param string $objet
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setObjet($objet)
    {
        $this->objet = $objet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get objet
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getObjet()
    {
        return $this->objet;
    }

    /**
     * Set moyenPaiement
     *
     * @param string $moyenPaiement
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setMoyenPaiement($moyenPaiement)
    {
        $this->moyenPaiement = $moyenPaiement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get moyenPaiement
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMoyenPaiement()
    {
        return $this->moyenPaiement;
    }

    /**
     * Set numeroCommande
     *
     * @param string $numeroCommande
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setNumeroCommande($numeroCommande)
    {
        $this->numeroCommande = $numeroCommande;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numeroCommande
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNumeroCommande()
    {
        return $this->numeroCommande;
    }

    /**
     * Set devise
     *
     * @param string $devise
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setDevise($devise)
    {
        $this->devise = $devise;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get devise
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDevise()
    {
        return $this->devise;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomFacturation
     *
     * @param string $nomFacturation
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setNomFacturation($nomFacturation)
    {
        $this->nomFacturation = $nomFacturation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomFacturation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomFacturation()
    {
        return $this->nomFacturation;
    }

    /**
     * Set tva
     *
     * @param string $tva
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setTva($tva)
    {
        $this->tva = $tva;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tva
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTva()
    {
        return $this->tva;
    }

    /**
     * Set reduction
     *
     * @param float $reduction
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setReduction($reduction)
    {
        $this->reduction = $reduction;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get reduction
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getReduction()
    {
        return $this->reduction;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresseFacturation
     *
     * @param string $adresseFacturation
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setAdresseFacturation($adresseFacturation)
    {
        $this->adresseFacturation = $adresseFacturation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresseFacturation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAdresseFacturation()
    {
        return $this->adresseFacturation;
    }

    /**
     * Set cpFacturation
     *
     * @param string $cpFacturation
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setCpFacturation($cpFacturation)
    {
        $this->cpFacturation = $cpFacturation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cpFacturation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCpFacturation()
    {
        return $this->cpFacturation;
    }

    /**
     * Set villeFacturation
     *
     * @param string $villeFacturation
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setVilleFacturation($villeFacturation)
    {
        $this->villeFacturation = $villeFacturation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get villeFacturation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getVilleFacturation()
    {
        return $this->villeFacturation;
    }

    /**
     * Set raison
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Raison $raison
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setRaison(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Raison $raison = null)
    {
        $this->raison = $raison;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get raison
     *
     * @return \VENTEBundle\Entity\Raison 
     */
    public function getRaison()
    {
        return $this->raison;
    }

    /**
     * Set compte
     *
     * @param \COMPTEBundle\Entity\Compte $compte
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setCompte(\COMPTEBundle\Entity\Compte $compte = null)
    {
        $this->compte = $compte;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get compte
     *
     * @return \COMPTEBundle\Entity\Compte 
     */
    public function getCompte()
    {
        return $this->compte;
    }

    /**
     * Add venteproduits
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Venteproduit $venteproduits
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function addVenteproduit(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Venteproduit $venteproduits)
    {
        $this->venteproduits[] = $venteproduits;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove venteproduits
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Venteproduit $venteproduits
     */
    public function removeVenteproduit(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Venteproduit $venteproduits)
    {
        $this->venteproduits->removeElement($venteproduits);
    }

    /**
     * Get venteproduits
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getVenteproduits()
    {
        return $this->venteproduits;
    }

    /**
     * Add ventedocuments
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Ventedocument $ventedocuments
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function addVentedocument(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Ventedocument $ventedocuments)
    {
        $this->ventedocuments[] = $ventedocuments;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove ventedocuments
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Ventedocument $ventedocuments
     */
    public function removeVentedocument(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Ventedocument $ventedocuments)
    {
        $this->ventedocuments->removeElement($ventedocuments);
    }

    /**
     * Get ventedocuments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getVentedocuments()
    {
        return $this->ventedocuments;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Vente
     */
    public function setUser(\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And this is the products entity (produit)

```
<?php

namespace VENTEBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Venteproduit
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VENTEBundle\Entity\VenteproduitRepository")
 */
class Venteproduit
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantite;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="montant_total", type="float")
     */
    private $montantTotal;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbr_personne", type="integer")
     */
    private $nbrPersonne;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="duree", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $duree;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $description;


     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vente", inversedBy="venteproduits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vente_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $vente;   


     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Produit", inversedBy="venteproduits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="produit_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $produit;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantite
     *
     * @param integer $quantite
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setQuantite($quantite)
    {
        $this->quantite = $quantite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantite
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getQuantite()
    {
        return $this->quantite;
    }

    /**
     * Set montantTotal
     *
     * @param float $montantTotal
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setMontantTotal($montantTotal)
    {
        $this->montantTotal = $montantTotal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get montantTotal
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getMontantTotal()
    {
        return $this->montantTotal;
    }

    /**
     * Set nbrPersonne
     *
     * @param integer $nbrPersonne
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setNbrPersonne($nbrPersonne)
    {
        $this->nbrPersonne = $nbrPersonne;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nbrPersonne
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNbrPersonne()
    {
        return $this->nbrPersonne;
    }

    /**
     * Set duree
     *
     * @param string $duree
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setDuree($duree)
    {
        $this->duree = $duree;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get duree
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDuree()
    {
        return $this->duree;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set vente
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Vente $vente
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setVente(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Vente $vente = null)
    {
        $this->vente = $vente;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vente
     *
     * @return \VENTEBundle\Entity\Vente 
     */
    public function getVente()
    {
        return $this->vente;
    }

    /**
     * Set produit
     *
     * @param \VENTEBundle\Entity\Produit $produit
     * @return Venteproduit
     */
    public function setProduit(\VENTEBundle\Entity\Produit $produit = null)
    {
        $this->produit = $produit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get produit
     *
     * @return \VENTEBundle\Entity\Produit 
     */
    public function getProduit()
    {
        return $this->produit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use arrays for your form element `name` attributes. Then you will have arrays in php. Probably something like `->add('raison[]')`, etc..

Comment: I've already tried it but i get the following error :

The name "quantite[]" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

Comment: You should check the symfony documentation on how to generate an array.

Comment: Can you provide code of the entity you create with this form and code of the entity you want to add multiple times

Comment: i added it in the top

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to create your products at the same time you create your sell or products must already exists ?

Comment: well to be specific : i have three entities vente(sell) venteproduit (sell-product) and produit (product).
the product entity is already full with a list of products and i want to add venteproduit and vente at the same time

Comment: Why do you need the VenteProduit entity ?

Comment: Thanks for your time. The relation between sell and product is many-to-many so i need a go-between entity that will  contain other informations like : quantity, amount, number of persons ...

Comment: It makes sense you can sell multiple products at a time and a product can be sold multiple times... But at the end of the day, each sell is unique. VenteProduit should simply be a transition table handled by Doctrine, not an entity. All attributes you put in that entity should be in your Vente entity

Comment: I agree with you, i could simply add venteproduit as an array in the sell table. 
Any way, i solved it by creating the fields directly in the view (with the help of jquery to duplicate the fields) and pushing it in the data base manually in the controller. It's not clean but it did the job . Thank you